# Multiple jquery versions on the same page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a website based on concrete5 CMS, its using old version of jquery to work.
Recently i needed to upgrade the main menu to be bootstrap responsive(navbar), but in order for it to collapse, bootstrap.js needs a newer version of jquery.

I cant get rid of the old one, and i need the new one for bootstrap to work, i know there is jquery.noconflict, but is there a way for all of the bootstrap.js to only use the new version of jquery, while the rest of the page will use the old one ?

Regards

Comment: It's not advisable to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the bootstrap navbar on multiple concrete5 site override the current jquery version with the lates for the collapse to work.

Either

1. If you are creating a custom theme, add the following where you define your JS files within script tags

   "getThemePath(); ?>/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"
2. If you are not using a custom theme, or you want to try a different way:

Dashboard -> System & Settings -> Tracking Codes

and then add:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it works for you, any questions just ask!

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, when i upload the new jquery the navbar collapse works, but i cant edit the page - the elements where you click and add items or blocks become unclickable due to the new version of jquery i assume :(

Comment: Concrete5 uses jquery anyway, if you have inserted any sort of jquery code into your sample pages, I would remove them and this should work. I replicated the problem and it worked for me!